# Send Message to Event Hub UWP

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-eventhub

**My Problem**

I need to send the Telemetry data to EventHub that I have created in my Azure Account using UWP.

I have created an web app (where I have given details on EventHub connection & Storage Area keys) - that which gets the data from EventHub and plots a real time graph using WebSocket.

**What I have tried**

I have a console app which uses ServiceBus dll to send data to EventHub.
When I tried to make a UWP the ServiceBus dll is not supported on Core .Net Framework

Can you show me some pointers or code snippet that would send data to EventHub.

Answer (score 2):

In Universal Apps, you have to use the new *Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs* NuGet package.

Quoting from this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send

```
 namespace SampleSender
 {
     using System;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;

     public class Program
     {
         private static EventHubClient eventHubClient;
         private const string EhConnectionString = "{Event Hubs connection string}";
         private const string EhEntityPath = "{Event Hub path/name}";

         public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
         }

         private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
         {
             // Creates an EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder object from a the connection string, and sets the EntityPath.
             // Typically the connection string should have the Entity Path in it, but for the sake of this simple scenario
             // we are using the connection string from the namespace.
             var connectionStringBuilder = new EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder(EhConnectionString)
             {
                 EntityPath = EhEntityPath
             };

             eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());

             await SendMessagesToEventHub(100);

             await eventHubClient.CloseAsync();

             Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
             Console.ReadLine();
         }

         // Creates an Event Hub client and sends 100 messages to the event hub.
         private static async Task SendMessagesToEventHub(int numMessagesToSend)
         {
             for (var i = 0; i < numMessagesToSend; i++)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     var message = $"Message {i}";
                     Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {message}");
                     await eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
                 }
                 catch (Exception exception)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} > Exception: {exception.Message}");
                 }

                 await Task.Delay(10);
             }

             Console.WriteLine($"{numMessagesToSend} messages sent.");
         }
     }
 }
```

So you install the NuGet package, create an `EventHubClient` from the connection string, and then use it to send messages:

```
await eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
```

Comment: I have been referring this article too and I also see the messages reaching the EventHub. But I would need the device(RaspberryPi3) to send messages.
 If I am using this code to send messages from Raspberry too I see the message (say RASP_MSG) reaching my EventHub.
But when I try to subscribe this data RASP_MSG I am not able to receive it in my Console App or Web App.

NOTE : But other messages (other than RASP_MSG) sent from my code (say Simulated_SENDER) can be received thru the same Console App\Web App.

What is the gap am missing here? Any idea please share.

Comment: That seems like an issue on your console app's end. Is it listening to all partitions?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. In EventHub only the _Incoming Requests_ are seen and no _messages_ are seen when the data are sent to EventHub from the device (in UWP) using the above code but with smal changes.
Changes done : 
 =========>1. removing`GetAwaiter().GetResult();`  from the Main Method.
 
========> 2.removing  _await_ from 
`await eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));`  

If the above changes (1) & (2) are not made then the system hangs i.e. it does not move from `await eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData...;` .
 Please guide me on next steps.